# Full screen android button click

Tags: android, android-button

My activity is full screen

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

I'm showing bunch of regular buttons but first touch just brings the navigation on the screen and user has to touch for second time to press the button .

How can I make the button be pressed on the first touch ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I not sure what do you want.
But for make the button clickable, you have to set onClickListener.

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO add your code here
            Log.d("DEBUG","PRESSED");
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the problem. Buttons have listeners and are clickable. The issue is that in full screen mode first touch just brings the navigation bar and to press the button I need to touch again . And I want to avoid the second touch.